# asp.net treeview programmatically setting node color

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I want to set the node colors of a treeview at runtime. I populate the treeview from a collection that has the parentid, childid, and description, and I've added a property representing the color I want applied to the node. FWIW the source is a database, the app is C#.

In a gridview I use RowDataBound() to programmatically affect the control.  Im not sure how to do so in the treeview, including which event to use (DataBound()? TreeViewDataBound()?). My research has not been fruitful so far. A code snippet would be very useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with the standard TreeView control, you can do this in the [TreeDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodedatabound.aspx).

A brief example (not tested):

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server"
    ID="tvMyTreeView"
    OnTreeNodeDataBound="tvMyTreeView_TreeNodeDataBound"
    />
```

And the backend:

```
protected void tvMyTreeView_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Node.DataItem;
    e.Node.Style.Add("color", dr["COLOR"].ToString());
}
```

If you are using the Telerik RadTreeView, then the event name is [NodeDataBound](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-server-node-databound.html)

You will probably have to tweak the example to better fit your needs, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: protected void tvToBeScheduled_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
MyClass mc = (MyClass)e.Node.DataItem;
            e.Node.Text = "<span style=\"color:"+src.NodeColor+"\">"+ src.NodeDescription+"</span>";
        }

Comment: @Aaron BDD: While I have not tried this answer, +1 for a good option.

Comment: The TreeNode class doesn't have a .Style property.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully this will give you a raging clue.

When setting a node text, instead of setting

```
Node Text
```

set as

```
<div style='color: red'>Node Text</a>
```

Comment: protected void tvToBeScheduled_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
MyClass mc = (MyClass)e.Node.DataItem;
e.Node.Text = "<span style=\"color:"+mc.NodeColor+"\">"+ mc.NodeDescription+"</span>";
}

Comment: I'm surprised the HTML isn't escaped as part of the Node rendering. But I can confirm this worked for me in ASP.Net 4.5.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Prerender event:

protected void TreeView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    if (IsPostBack) return;

    foreach (TreeNode t in TreeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (t.Value.EndsWith("1")) //Some Condition
        {
            string s = t.Text;
            string fs = "<span style=\"color: #CC0000\">" + s + "</span>";
            t.Text = fs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET Framework 4.5 you can use these style properties:

- [TreeView.LevelStyles Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.levelstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) - represent the node styles at the
  individual levels of the tree
- [TreeView.RootNodeStyle Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.rootnodestyle(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TreeView.ParentNodeStyle Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.parentnodestyle(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TreeView.LeafNodeStyle
  Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.leafnodestyle(v=vs.110).aspx)