# How to change the Forecolor of tree view node?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

How to conditionally change the forecolor of treeview node in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this.It works for me

```
if (Condition)
                {

                    string str = text to change color;
                    string fstr = "<span style=\"color: #2E2EFE\">" + s + "</span>";
                    text to change color = fstr;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do code as shown below

```
//Use Namespace 
       using System.Drawing;

  //Display the Node names with and Orange font.
    YourNode.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
```

Comment: Hi,I cannot set ForeColor Property.

Comment: No.Its not working for me.Fore color property is not showing for me.

Comment: Sorry,I am not getting.

Comment: Are you able to add name space  - using System.Drawing; ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that I misunderstand your question but here is an idea: use javascript and a suitable trigger (onclick, onchange, ...) that runs some javascript snippet which aims to change the treeview color:

```
<div onClick="ChangeColorJavascript()">
 <asp:TreeView runat="server">
    <Nodes>
      <asp:TreeNode Text="My Computer">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Favorites"></asp:TreeNode>
      </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
  </asp:TreeView>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry,I didn't mention that i want to change the color while binding the data

Comment: Well, then I might have looked at a suitable server event, like [`TreeView.TreeNodeDataBound Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodedatabound(v=vs.110).aspx). This occurs when an item is bound to the control.

I believe that this SO-question is pretty close to what you want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219788/asp-net-treeview-programatically-setting-node-color

Comment: I am able to get 'Style' Property in my TreeNodeDataBound event